# How can we identify the type of password

Tags: android, security, passwords

In android device we have five type of password

1. None
2. slide
3. pattern
4. password
5. PIN

How can I identify which type of password is used by the user?
Android provides `DevicePolicyManger` but it does not gives this information.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing is [getPasswordQuality()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#getPasswordQuality%28android.content.ComponentName%29).

Comment: it returns what is policy is applied on device like  PASSWORD_QUALITY_ALPHABETIC
PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC
Now How can we recognize, this is PASSWORD ,PIN,PATTERN

Comment: Use your imagination -- PIN -> NUMERIC, PASSWORD -> ALPHABETIC, etc.

Comment: When the password quality is Numeric then u can set alphanumeric password also

Comment: Well, sure, that's the minimum requirement. If you set a stronger password, you are obviously fulfilling it. As I said, it's close. What exactly are you trying to do and why?